# Selenium status 6 on protractor execution

Tags: automation, webdriver, protractor

We are using protractor with jasmine for our test automation, and recently we started getting the following error in the middle of an execution which cases failure of random specs:

```
     E/BlockingProxy - Got status 6 from selenium { error: 'invalid session id',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]   message: 'No active session with ID ff5c8c9ef2782fe1bcc2212cf9d7a3ed',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]   stacktrace: '' }
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3] [11:23:33] E/BlockingProxy - Got status 13 from selenium { class: 'org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]   error: 'unknown error',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]   message: 'Session [ff5c8c9ef2782fe1bcc2212cf9d7a3ed] was terminated due to BROWSER_TIMEOUT',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]   stackTrace: 
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]    [ { className: 'org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        fileName: 'ActiveTestSessions.java',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        lineNumber: 115,
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        methodName: 'getExistingSession' },
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]      { className: 'org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        fileName: 'DefaultGridRegistry.java',
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        lineNumber: 379,
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]        methodName: 'getExistingSession' },
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]      { className: 'org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler',
```

After this is thrown, the spec continues to execute and it fails with:

```
 - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
11:23:55      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-3]           at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
```

Has anyone seen these errors? We are out of ideas on what could be the cause.

Some additional info: our tests are executed with maxInstance = 3, shartTestFiles=true. We are using:

- latest chrome browser 69.0.3497
- selenium server - 3.14.0
- chrome driver - 2.42
- protractor - 5.3.2

Output from selenium hub:

```
11:06:14.905 WARN [RequestHandler.process] - The client is gone for session ext. key 9452459edd7adcf782ec59c68f665a6c, terminating
```

Comment: what's the value of `seleniumAddress` in your protractor's conf.js?

Comment: It is using a Selenium hub - where the selenium server is version 3.14.0 and is deployed on another host. However, the same error appears upon localhost execution where we use webdriver-manager and the seleniumAddress is simply localhost:4444

Comment: From the error message,  the issue is the opened browser instance is closed when next test case trying to run on one launched browser instance.  Did you close browser after each case, like using some `AfterEach` hook.